# Handling a Stripe customer creation error client side

Tags: javascript, php, promise, stripe-payments

I've been using Stripe to successfully process payments. The payment intent is created in PHP on the server and there is client side scripting in javascript to set up and call the payment intent script and handle the results.

If something like a card declined happens, then this is handled fine. However if there is a different kind of problem then although I can successfully trap this error server side, I've been unable to work out how to handle it client side and display a useful error message to the user.

This is my client side code:

```
var stripe = "***HIDDEN***";
var stripesetup = "/stripecreate.php";
var subscriptionid = document.getElementById("subscriptionid").value;
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

// The items the customer wants to buy
var purchase = {
  items: [{ id: subscriptionid }]
};

// Disable the button until we have Stripe set up on the page
document.getElementById("btn-checkout").disabled = true;
fetch(stripesetup, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(purchase)
}).then(function(result) {
     /* This is where the error should be trapped, however result isn't the value from the server side script */
    return result.json();
}).catch( (message) => {
     /* Have also been trying to handle 'message' in here but without success */
}).then(function(data) {
    var elements = stripe.elements();

    var style = {
      base: {
        color: "#32325d",
        fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
        fontSize: "16px",
        "::placeholder": {
          color: "#32325d"
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
        color: "#fa755a",
        iconColor: "#fa755a"
      }
    };

    // Stripe injects an iframe into the DOM
    var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
    card.mount("#card-element");
    
    /*
    var cardNumberElement = elements.create('cardNumber');
    cardNumberElement.mount("#card-element");

    var cardExpiryElement = elements.create('cardExpiry');
    cardExpiryElement.mount("#cardexpiry-element");
    */
    
    card.on("change", function (event) {
      // Disable the Pay button if there are no card details in the Element
      document.getElementById("btn-checkout").disabled = event.empty;
      document.querySelector("#shopvalidation").textContent = event.error ? event.error.message : "";
    });

    var form = document.getElementById("shopform5");
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    
      // Complete payment when the submit button is clicked
      payWithCard(stripe, card, data.clientSecret);
    });
    
});

// Calls stripe.confirmCardPayment
// If the card requires authentication Stripe shows a pop-up modal to
// prompt the user to enter authentication details without leaving your page.
var payWithCard = function(stripe, card, clientSecret) {
  loading(true);
  stripe
    .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
      receipt_email: email,
      payment_method: {
        card: card
      }
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Show error to your customer
        showError(result.error.message);
      } else {
        // The payment succeeded!
        orderComplete(result.paymentIntent.id);
      }
    });
};

/* ------- UI helpers ------- */

// Shows a success message when the payment is complete
var orderComplete = function(paymentIntentId) {
  loading(false);
  document.getElementById("btn-checkout").disabled = true;
  location.href="/thank-you";  
};

// Show the customer the error from Stripe if their card fails to charge
var showError = function(errorMsgText) {
  loading(false);
  var errorMsg = document.querySelector("#shopvalidation");
  errorMsg.textContent = "Unfortunately your payment has been unsuccessful due to "+errorMsgText+" Please contact us for more information";
  setTimeout(function() {
    errorMsg.textContent = "";
  }, 10000);
};

// Show a spinner on payment submission
var loading = function(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.getElementById("btn-checkout").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#lds-ring").classList.remove("invisible");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("invisible");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("btn-checkout").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#lds-ring").classList.add("invisible");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("invisible");
  }
};
```

On the server, the payment intent is being created with this:

```
        try {
            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
                'name' => $fullname,
                'email' => $email,
                'phone' => $telephone,
                "shipping" => [
                    'name' => $fullname,
                    "address" => [
                        "line1" => $address1,
                        "line2" => $address2,
                        "city" => $town,
                        "state" => $county,
                        "country" => $countrycode
                    ],
                ],
                "address" => [
                    "line1" => $billingaddress1,
                    "line2" => $billingaddress2,
                    "city" => $billingtown,
                    "state" => $billingcounty,
                    "country" => $billingcountrycode
                ],
                'description' => $userid
            ]);

            $stripeid = $customer->id;
    
        } catch(\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
          // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Exception\CardException will be caught
          echo 'Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . '\n';
          echo 'Type is:' . $e->getError()->type . '\n';
          echo 'Code is:' . $e->getError()->code . '\n';
          echo 'Param is:' . $e->getError()->param . '\n';
          echo 'Message is:' . $e->getError()->message . '\n';
          die();
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\RateLimitException $e) {
          // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
          echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
          die();
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException $e) {
          // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
          echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
          die();
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\AuthenticationException $e) {
          // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
          // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
          echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
          die();
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiConnectionException $e) {
          // Network communication with Stripe failed
          echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
          die();
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
          // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
          // yourself an email
          echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
          die();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
          echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
          die();
        }
    }
```

An "\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException" is being thrown in my testing when I delibrately put in an invalid phone number. This is being returned by my stripecreate.php script:

```
{"error":"Invalid string: 0123456789...0123456789; must be at most 20 characters"}
```

I would expect this to be handled in the first part of the promise indicated in my client side script above, however the result is returning this when echoed to the console:

```
Response { type: "basic", url: "https://www.HIDDEN*****/stripecreate.php", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers(11), body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
​
body: ReadableStream { locked: true }
​
bodyUsed: true
​
headers: Headers(11) { "cache-control" → "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate", "content-length" → "82", "content-type" → "application/json", … }
​
ok: true
​
redirected: false
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
type: "basic"
​
url: "https://www.HIDDEN*****/stripecreate.php"
​
<prototype>: ResponsePrototype { clone: clone(), arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer(), blob: blob(), … }
```

I expect this is me not correctly understanding how the promise structure is working and how I can get the response text from the server so I can check for an error and display it.

The next .then in the promise carries on execution even though I want it to stop at that point.

Been scratching my head over this one all day. Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your server is responding with JSON & 200 status code, so the first `.then()` callback only parses the response and moves on.

The status of the response being `200`, it is unlikely that it'll be caught by the `.catch()` function too.

So you'd likely want to handle this response in the following `.then()` call.

Have you tried responding with a different response code (4xx) or (5xx) to see if that triggers `.catch()` callback?

Comment: Thank you for this. Adding http_response_code(400) to the back end code causes the catch block to kick in, although I can't see how to handle the 'message' parameter? Outputting it to the console gives me "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". The following .then block continues execution (I want to stop then if an error happened). I can show a generic message to the client at this point, however I'd like to be able to show the message my back end script is returning and also stop execution from continuing in the next .then block.